# azure-devops pipeline test pass reports use the wrong math

Tags: azure-devops

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline where 40% of tests are inactive. The report shows 60% pass rate when it should (in my opinion) show 100%, because usually the pass rate is defined against tests executed not the universe of tests that were written.

I have searched the Microsoft documentation where the only answer is to check stackoverflow where I haven't seen this issue be reported.

Would someone please tell me how I can filter the inactive tests out of the report? Thanks!

Comment: Hi friend, not getting your latest info. Can my workaround work for you? Feel free to let me know if you have any concern about it.

Comment: sorry, I didn't have time to get back to stackoverflow to report back. and thanks again for detailing the solution for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The report shows 60% pass rate when it should (in my opinion) show
> 100%, because usually the pass rate is defined against tests executed
> not the universe of tests that were written.

**Scenario:**

I have five test methods in which 3 of them will succeed and 1 of them will fail, the fifth test method is marked with `Ignore` attribute.

**Reproduce same issue:**

For test report of VSTest task, the Ignored tests will be marked as `other`. And the Total tests is the summary of `Passed+Failed+Others` instead of `Passed+Failed`, so you get 60% instead of 100%.

[image]

Here's [one discussion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/911441/azure-devops-ignored-unit-tests-affects-pass-perce.html) about similar issue, as I know the team has added further investigation of whether or not to use ignored tests in summary calculation to backlog. You can comment there to ask for update.

> Would someone please tell me how I can filter the inactive tests out
> of the report? Thanks!

My working workaround is to use `TestCategory` instead of `Ignore` attribute. Change from `Ignore` to `TestCategory`:

From:

```
[Ignore]
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod5()
{
    bool value = true;
    if (value.Equals(true))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("True");
    }
}
```

To:

```
[TestCategory("TestsToBeIgnored")]
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod5()
{
    bool value = true;
    if (value.Equals(true))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("True");
    }
}
```

Configure the VSTest Test Filter, add the filter `TestCategory!=TestsToBeIgnored`.

[image]

[image]

So that the total tests do exclude the tests which I need to ignore, and the percentage can be accurate. (The `Test filter` option works for Azure Devops pipeline, local vstest command-line and VS Test manager)

Comment: thank you @ Lance Li -- it seems to do the trick. I will try it and report back.

Comment: @krazyk4tlady Feel free to let me know if my answer helps or not :)

Comment: your solution is a workaround Microsoft's rigid (and incorrect) interpretation of what is a pass rate. So it works, yes. I also took the opportunity to reply on their website and request that they make the report customizable if they care so much for their definition of pass rate

Comment: If you can't get a quick response from the Closed ticket, feel free to create a new feature request by [this page](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html), the team would consider it when they view it.